# Radius around touched position

Tags: java, android, math, view, touch

I have a ArrayList of X & Y coordinates which are located in a View. Now I want to check if the user touches the view, if some of the stored X & Y coordinates are in a certain radius (Like 20 Pixel) around the touched point. How would I be able to implement this?

Best regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Pythagorean formula.

```
if(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(stored_x - touched_x, 2) + Math.pow(stored_y - touched_y, 2)) <= 20){
    //do thing
}
```